# How load Jinja2 template into Environment's loader from database

Tags: jinja2

FileSystemLoader loads templates from a directory, Is there anyway I could pull the template from a database as string into loader ?

```
env = Environment(
    #loader=FileSystemLoader(templates),
    loader = Filedb('template.j2') # fetch from db ?    
    undefined=StrictUndefined # Force variable to be defined
  )
env.filters['custom_filter'] = func

t = env.get_template("template.j2")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jinja docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#loaders):

> If you want to create your own loader, subclass **BaseLoader** and override *get_source*.

For example:

```
class DatabaseLoader(BaseLoader):

  def __init__(self, database_credentials):
    self.database_credentials = database_credentials

  def get_source(self, environment, template):
    # Load from database... an exercise for the reader.
```

Because templates can depend on other templates, loading one template could require multiple database lookups. Database lookups could be minimized using [bytecode caching](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#bytecode-cache) to cache compiled templates.

It is also possible to load all of the templates from the database into a dictionary, and then load the dictionary using Jinja's [DictLoader](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.DictLoader).

Comment: would this work for templates that inherit/extend other templates also within the database? Do you have an example of what that might look like?

Comment: @CharlieMorton Yes, loading from database allows use of inherit and extend. One caveat is possible performance issues, because each inherit / extend is a separate call to the database. However, I think Jinja has internal caching that might mitigate any performance issues. In the past, I've loaded all of the templates from the database into a dictionary, and then loaded the dictionary using DictLoader.

Comment: @CharlieMorton For use with inherit and extend, what would normally (when using the FileSystemLoader) be the relative path to the template, is now the database key, or the dictionary key, for loading that template.